# self referencing generics in the class initializer

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider this class definition:

```
class MyClass<T extends Record<string, unknown> = any> {
  constructor(
    public params: {
      methodOne: (data: Record<string, unknown>) => T;
      methodTwo: (data: T) => void;
    }
  ) {
    // ...
  }
}
// OK
const myClassInstance = new MyClass({
  methodOne: (data) => {
    return {
      name: "foo",
      lastName: "bar",
    };
  },
  methodTwo: (data) => {
    console.log(data.lastName); //ok
    console.log(data.name); //ok
  },
})
```

So what I'm trying to do is infer the `data` parameter in the `methodTwo` (which comes from the `methodOne` and this works correctly in this kind of setup, when arguments are created `inline` when instantiating the class instance.

Now I wanna do the same thing but instead of declaring the `methodTwo` directly in the params argument to the `MyClass` instance I want to have it somewhere else in the code, and this is where I get the dreaded (7022) error

```
// NOT OK
//'myClassInstanceTwo' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation 
//and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)
const myClassInstanceTwo = new MyClass({
  methodOne: (data) => {
    return {
      name: "foo",
      lastName: "bar",
    };
  },
  methodTwo: methodTwoExternal,
});

type MethodOneReturn<T extends MyClass> = ReturnType<T["params"]["methodOne"]>;
// 'data' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.(2502)
function methodTwoExternal(data: MethodOneReturn<typeof myClassInstanceTwo>) {
  console.log(data.lastName); //ok
  console.log(data.name); //ok
}
```

Is there a way to make this work?
I'm open to changing the `MyClass` constructor signature, maybe even introduce a `factory` function for the class instantiation.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-jQAZkgQ1Zz3POL-NvIVQAKL4INXEAspTqzVwbKbXwUEenDDYE8kGAIDsQMSSB+j9DO1A6nQABtAAicxLBsUCAF0wP3LYYIUEReWgG5qT1Zh-SwQNg1Dc0EyjJVY1YcNIyTONU3TYQnWvaQ3TwD1CELMsAFZy1ZO4eE0Rj1hycVjwIU4c2xWxYFvbx72OJ8rywKg7mGT8G1FcURCaOoyRRdFMWxXFGEXLB6UZRwNIpbTqVRSdDJJeogA)

Comment: At some point you either annotate your way out of the circularity (give up on inference) or write your code to not be circular (e.g., as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4avew)). TS's inference algorithm is heuristic in nature and optimized for more common use cases, so... why are you trying to do it this way? What is gained from not just... annotating your types if you have an external function?

Comment: Consider this code to be a third party package and I'm trying to create a good developer experience.

I'm trying to avoid the situation where end-user needs to do this "manually" I would like to offer some helper types that the user could use in order to extract methodOne return type.

Comment: Which part is third-party, your `MyClass`? Why would someone writing a standalone function have a worse developer experience annotating their parameter types (which is the way just about all TS functions are written) compared to having to do something like `MethodOneReturn<typeof myClassInstanceTwo>`? I'm having a hard time seeing the benefit or imagining the user for whom the helper types are more intuitive than annotations. Does the user not know the return type of `method1` already? Did someone else write `method1` for them?

Comment: Like, you could make a builder as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5aqZN), but... why would anyone want to use that? I'd rather just define `methodTwoExternal` inline (so it's not external) or fully independently (without `typeof` in there anywhere).  Still, it does seem to meet the requirements from your question, so... would such an approach constitute an acceptable answer for you?

Comment: I think I need to approach my problem differently, but in terms of the question, the builder approach is acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can think of here (assuming this pattern is something we need to support) would be to make some sort of [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) that lets you set `methodOne` first, then get an intermediate thing that lets you extract the type `T` from it, and then lets you set `methodTwo` and finally gives you a `MyClass<T>` instance. Something like:

```
class MyClass<T extends Record<string, unknown> = any> {    
  static builder = {
    m1<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
      methodOne: (data: Record<string, unknown>) => T) {
      return {
        __type: null! as T,
        m2(methodTwo: (data: T) => void) {
          return new MyClass({ methodOne, methodTwo })
        }
      }
    }
  }
  constructor(public params: {
    methodOne: (data: Record<string, unknown>) => T
    methodTwo: (data: T) => void
  }) { }    
}
```

So `MyClass.builder.m1(method1).m2(method2)` is the same as `new MyClass(method1, method2)`, but now you can pause at `MyClass.builder.m1(method1)` and inspect it for the type you care about. To make that easy I added a dummy/phantom `__type` property, so that the type is like `typeof xxx.__type` instead of something awful like `Parameters<Parameters<typeof xxx.m2>[0]>[0]`.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const myClassInstanceTwoBuilder =
  MyClass.builder.m1((data) => {
    return {
      name: 'foo',
      lastName: 'bar'
    }
  });

function methodTwoExternal(data: typeof myClassInstanceTwoBuilder.__type) {
  console.log(data.lastName) //ok
  console.log(data.name) //ok
}

const myClassInstanceTwo =
  myClassInstanceTwoBuilder.m2(methodTwoExternal);
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGAJS2AHsAnY1CPGgS0IHMAaaAV0IGtCVAO6EAfNAC80MIXjiA3gChF0aIzB5mwaACNuzEMSw1J0JatUBbAIwZs+IqWgVqdBk1ace-QSNGiAChULKyw8AAsqYgB5QiwALmgA4g0wRJdaekYWdi5eAWExAEpJcXQS8xDoGjDuGkIzYKroAH0WvHgABwToQm4QEABCaRh0DiaqywAmAMswyOJ0ISpE5NTE8tLoADcqZmIKieaavDqGuKE4JBQIAPloOYio2KwuR4WlqmgAXyKji2+-0BIWBP2C1EI2W4wDwtACnW4OhAWmgnTANDAlggiUqoSeMTiqxSeDSzkomXcOS8+V8xS26Am7yinyJ62gmwk4l2+2CvzMYMUgMUEMYD2ukAgAElISTCMAsKYLldkBK7sEmQSemsSSVOY0QiczvqqoRMT0AOQAMyoVHN42aKDwADkzYlzTp0eaJqDvvaHvNmctWTqtrjoCKqCAsAA6EBUNjasCxyDOs0lAD06aofAmEajsfjiejprmGazOdUvsFf2FVBlYpVUGl6jlWE+ACF9IZjJJgghGxBo3oDEYaNGbAFE7qFBNDfVjSESxbrba-SFHS65m6PTQvSDeUUANzKDrdaAAQRAECoAHVaHwIJ28ABNaF8UwABXRZoINAgqC-DFHmMf9TywKhLQbG5m1leUOy7UdxymUQAG0AAYAF1UMw5RLV4GFmDrf18U+ABRBx6jAEBE0SMCIKgiUYJkODlk7EdjGjNowMOVQ8xjOME2JJMNzTaBM2zcE62vfMBKLJcywkoURTwBimxlZi22WXsrHFNSWxYqg2O7MdplmANFmWcjf1NEAj0UIA)